# Web api custom routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Controller called QuotaController, and i can access it via httprequests, like this:

> localhost:12345/quota/

What i want is to put an endpoint somewhere so i can access it like:

> localhost:12345/quota/increment

or

> localhost:12345/quota/decrement

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your web api route definition to allow passing an action name:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And then:

```
public class QuotaController : ApiController
{
    public void Increment()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have a route like that, right now quotacontroller looks like this:
public class QuotaController : ApiController
    {
      public HttpResponseMessage GetQuota(int id){}
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SetQuota(int id, DocType doc, QuotaType quota, int value){}
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Increment{}
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Decrement{}
}
Can i have more than one post request in one controller?

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one POST action.

Comment: Your url seems to be missing the `api` prefix. Shouldn't it be  `localhost:15339/api/quota/increment`? At least that's how it should be according to the route definition I've shown in my answer.

Comment: i just got your comment, sorry: i left the api prefix from the route, but also from the request, so it's okay like that. but the Increment and Decrement has the same parametering, and i get multiple actions were found error :/

Comment: But if you remove the `api` prefix how are you able to disambiguate between your API controllers and your standard controllers? Or in this ASP.NET MVC application you only have API controllers and not UI?